# How to change the values of input boxes present in html dynamic table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have to edit the input boxes present in html dynamic table td tag. Each td contain two text boxes . please tell me how to edit those text boxes using jquery.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpukN.png)

Comment: Add relevant code here at SO. Help yourself first then others will follow

Comment: Hi balaji, I'm afraid you're going to have to add some html and whatever jQuery you have already tried before we can help.

Comment: Where is you code? Are you fetching data from the database? Normally the input should be editable, but first show us your code,then we can help u